# django philosophy: when to include templates and when to have code generate html?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

When using Django templates, should I have some templates that act like "subroutines", so to speak, or should I generate HTML from within my code in these cases?

For example, I have a template with several lists of names, each of which I want to turn into a `select`. Should I have a template that renders the `name_list` variable into a select, and do something like this:

```
#in the view:
return {'name_list_1': name_list_1, 
        'name_list_2': name_list_2, 
        'name_list_3': name_list_3}

#in the template:
{% with name_list_1 as name_list %}
  {% include "sub_name_list_select.html" %}
{% endwith %}
{% with name_list_2 as name_list %}
  {% include "sub_name_list_select.html" %}
{% endwith %}
{% with name_list_3 as name_list %}
  {% include "sub_name_list_select.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Or should I have a function in my code, `name_list_to_select_html`, which does the same job, and do this:

```
return {'name_list_1_html': name_list_to_select_html(name_list_1), 
        'name_list_2_html': name_list_to_select_html(name_list_2), 
        'name_list_3_html': name_list_to_select_html(name_list_3)}

#in the template:
{{ name_list_1_html|safe }}
{{ name_list_2_html|safe }}
{{ name_list_3_html|safe }}
```

Or are both of these wrong and I am getting the philosophy totally wrong?

Additional question: in terms of speed, is it slow to constantly include templates? Is that a bonus point for the in-code html generation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. This might be more appropriate some place like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: which particular criteria does this question fall under? it seems pretty straightforward to me: how do django developers accomplish this task?

Comment: It's a subjective question. The bulleted list merely provides examples of common subjective questions, but if you're asking what people recommend, your question is subjective and not appropriate for StackOverflow. Like I said, the Code Review site would be okay because the entire nature of *that* site is to gain subjective opinions.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: ah ok, i think you're right. voting to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, HTML should only be generated in the templating system or directly related code.  That keeps the view of the data completely separate from the business and functional logic.  I feel that's a proper [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  Go with your first solution.

As for performance, Django should probably take around the same amount of time running either code.  But it has built-in view and template fragment caching if you know those segments of code don't need to be regenerated on every request.

Comment: is my first solution the commonly-accepted way to pass variables to templates, or is there something more elegant? something irks me about not being able to call a template like a function.

Comment: also, due to the limited nature of django templating, i am invariably forced to have the view of the data interfere with the python code, as i have to return data structures amenable to the templating system. for example, if i want to pass a dict, it's hard to get the templating system to sort it, so i end up having to turn it into a list of items and do the sorting on the view code. isn't having the views in `views.py` enough separation?

Comment: Views gather the data to present (in an easy-to-template way), but I believe all HTML should be done directly at the template level.  When I require more python functionality to write HTML, I create custom tags and filters.  You also have the option of using a different templating system (although I've never tried it myself).